# Gnuplot - coloring a plot according to x-value

Tags: colors, gnuplot

I would like to change the color of a plot according to the x-value, for a function plot (i.e. not from a data file). 
For example, I define a palette as follows: 
`set palette defined ( 0 'purple', 1 'blue', 2 'green', 3 'yellow', 4 'orange', 5 'red' )` 
and I wish to use the color the function `sin(x)` using my palette according to the x value for the range [0:5]. 
How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `linecolor palette` for this purpose, which requires the specification of an additional column that contains the color information. For a function plot you can use the special filename `'+'` to have the full versatility of the `using` command at your disposal:

```
set palette defined ( 0 'purple', 1 'blue', 2 'green', 3 'yellow', 4 'orange', 5 'red' )
set xrange [0:5]
plot '+' using 1:(sin($1)):1 with lines linewidth 3 linecolor palette
```

[image]

Comment: I came across this nice solution but I'm not good enough with gnuplot to know what is happening with `1:(sin($1)):1`. Could you please elaborate a little bit if possible? I have been reading about indexing, columns and pseudo columns, etc but it gets confusing specially with additional details such as parentheses.